# PostgreSQL 9.4 jsonb how ro query

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4.2, jsonb

I have currently a Sheet model , with a specific jsonb attribute :

```
      create_table "sheets", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.integer  "user_id",    default: 0,    null: false
        t.boolean  "private",    default: true, null: false
        t.jsonb    "t_data",     default: {},   null: false
      end
```

in the t_data jsonb attribute, I'll store a list ( so multiple lines ) which content should be like this :

```
    def sample_3_content
      {
        headings: [
          "Rendering engine",
          "Browser",
          "Platform",
          "Engine version",
          "CSS grade"
        ],
        rows: {
                "line_0":{
                  "Rendering engine":"Trident",
                  "Browser":"Internet Explorer 4.0",
                  "Platform":"Win 95+",
                  "Engine version":"4.0",
                  "CSS grade":"X"
                },            
                "line_1":{
                  "Rendering engine":"Trident",
                  "Browser":"Internet Explorer 5.0",
                  "Platform":"Win 95+",
                  "Engine version":"5",
                  "CSS grade":"C"
                },
```

this query

```
Sheet('rows @> ?', {"CSS grade" => "X" }.to_json)
```

is raising an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `Sheet' for main:Object
```

I am not sure it's the best schema ... as I would like to query all lines on the different headings, i.e. "CSS grade" == "X"  , "Browser" contains "Explorer" ...

Any suggestions for rewriting my schema are welcome ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is not to use `"line_0"` key, as it looks excessive in the structure you have provided for your JSONB content column. It would be much more flexible use plain array for `"rows"` key. Example DDL with sample data may look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE sheets (content JSONB);
INSERT INTO sheets VALUES
    ('{
     "headings": [
       "Rendering engine",
       "Browser",
       "Platform",
       "Engine version",
       "CSS grade"
     ],
     "rows": [{
                  "Rendering engine":"Trident",
                  "Browser":"Internet Explorer 4.0",
                  "Platform":"Win 95+",
                  "Engine version":"4.0",
                  "CSS grade":"X"
        },
        {
                  "Rendering engine":"Trident",
                  "Browser":"Internet Explorer 5.0",
                  "Platform":"Win 95+",
                  "Engine version":"5",
                  "CSS grade":"C"
        }
     ]
     }'::JSONB);
```

In this case you have much more freedom for querying array elements, than explicitly saying `row->'line_X'->>'jsonAttribute'`. Example query can be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM sheets,jsonb_array_elements(content->'rows') as row
WHERE row->>'CSS grade' = 'X' 
AND row->>'Platform' = 'Win 95+';
```